# GRAPH API INSTAGRAM - get metrics values in a range dates

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have the following query:

```
[object media ID]/insights/?metric=reach&since2019-12-02&until=2019-12-22
```

It has been returning lifetime values (filter by date does not work). Then I added "`period=day`" to add all values, but the response is:

```
(#100) The following periods (day) are incompatible with the metric (reach)
```

How i could get a metric’s total value in a range dates?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Instagram Graph API **Media** (Object) Insights endpoint doesn't support all the fancy filters of the **User** Insights endpoint.

So I'd ask, are you doing this on an instagram media object or on a user object? My guess is that you're doing it on a media object which is why you'd get that error. I ran these calls on both media and user objects to get to the bottom of this.

If you're doing a *user* object, you can only max out at 28 days of range. So if you use your date range, you'd request like this:

[instagram-id] /insights/?metric=reach&period=days_28&since2019-12-02&until=2019-12-22

Since your data range is under 28 days, you will get the Reach of all this instagram user's content in that range.

sample:

```css
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "reach",
      "period": "days_28",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 620,
          "end_time": "2019-12-20T08:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 623,
          "end_time": "2019-12-21T08:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Reach",
      "description": "Total number of times the Business Account's media objects have been uniquely viewed",
      "id": "17841400804152929/insights/reach/days_28"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    ....
  }
}
```

Impressions and Reach have the same period options for user objects; day, week, 28_day.

So to use period, since and until, you can only perform on a User object and not media.

User Insights (with filters) --> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights#insights-2

Media Insights (lifetime only) --> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights#insights-2

For a side reference, if you were to do this call on facebook, for a post for instance, you'd use the metric post_impressions_unique which is 'reach' on FB. FB has way more filters.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/insights

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. I have taking holiday I will try it in a month 15 days when i go back.

Comment: Period also has `"period": "lifetime"` option for engagement, impressions and reach.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
[instagram-id] /insights/?metric=reach&since=1575244800&until=1576972800
```

2019-12-02 = 1575244800

2019-12-22 = 1576972800

This is a [unix timestamp conversion](https://onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

I try with the graph api v8.0 for FB post and work!